# Nextjs 10.0.6 rewrite error on vercel 502 `TOO_MANY_FILESYSTEM_CHECKS `

Tags: deployment, next.js, vercel

I am getting a `TOO_MANY_FILESYSTEM_CHECKS` error on `Vercel` trying to make an api call using rewrite to route requests to the api. Everything works fine locally.

next.config:

```
 module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/my-api/:path*',
        destination: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/:path*`,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Usage

```
import {GraphQLClient} from "graphql-request"
...
...
export default new GraphQLClient("/my-api/graphql")
```

Same code works fine on next@11.0.1. Any pointer, please??

Comment: I have seen your issue https://github.com/vercel/vercel/issues/6450 and I am also facing the same. May be you check on this if this workaround can fix for you https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/15793#discussioncomment-45893

Comment: And I am facing this issue on next@11.0.1 itself

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read so far you can't have more than seven rewrites so I'm imagining since you have the * it could be considering it as having too many rewrites.